# How to set width and height for window.opener() function?

Tags: javascript, popup, facebook-social-plugins, window.opener

There is a social login wordpress plugin that produces a large popup window when authenticating a login from a social networking site (facebook, google, etc.)

I would like to make the popup window much smaller, but can't figure it out. The code the produces the popup window is:

```
if( get_option( 'wsl_settings_use_popup' ) == 1 || ! get_option( 'wsl_settings_use_popup' ) ){
    ?>
        <html><head><script>
        function init() {
            window.opener.wsl_wordpress_social_login({
                'action'   : 'wordpress_social_login',
                'provider' : '<?php echo $provider ?>'
            });

            window.close()
        }
```

How do I set the width and height for this popup?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code is not the one which open the popup. What is the real plugin name?

Comment: The plugin is Wordpress Social Login: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/

Comment: have you already installed it? can I see that popup?

Comment: I need it to understand what code I have to search

Comment: Check the edit if you can't find the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR CENTERED WINDOW**

Add this 2 calculation just under `provider = $(this).attr("data-provider");`:

```
datop = (($(document).height()-400)/2);
daleft = (($(document).width()-225)/2);
```

Add this 2 parameters to the attributes:

```
top="+datop+",left="+daleft+""
```

like this:

```
"location=1,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=225,height=400,top="+datop+",left="+daleft+""
```

**END**

**Edit**

You can find the file here: wp-content/plugins/wordpress-social-login/assets/js/connect.js

**End edit**

The file is "wordpress-social-login\assets\js\connect.js" I don't know where this file will be installed, but probably you can find the function inside it in every page which contain the login (if you can locate it, you can unistall, edit the file and the reinstall with the file modified). This should be the function you are searching for:

```
(function($){ 
    $(function(){
        $(".wsl_connect_with_provider").click(function(){//selector.event
            popupurl = $("#wsl_popup_base_url").val();//assign text of the element with id #wls_popup_base..
            provider = $(this).attr("data-provider");//assign the attribute data-provider of the element with class .wls_connect.. 

            window.open(
                popupurl+"provider="+provider,//url
                "hybridauth_social_sing_on", //window name
                "location=1,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=1000,height=600"//attributes of the window
            ); 
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This should be the code of the popup

```
window.open(
    popupurl+"provider="+provider,
    "hybridauth_social_sing_on",
    "location=1,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=1000,height=600"
);
```

To change width and height,edit this 2 params: `..width=1000,height=600"`

Note that i add the comments to let you understand what the function do and what are you doing

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. Do you know if there is a way to make it open in the center of the page instead of the top left hand corner?

Comment: @Alex what dimension have you set?

Comment: window.open(
    popupurl+"provider="+provider,
    "hybridauth_social_sing_on", 
    "location=no,status=0,scrollbars=0,width=400,height=225"

Comment: @Alex thank you, Please, try to do less damage possible with that kind of site ;) ..